# Symfony Assetic featurejust seem not to work

Tags: symfony, bundle, assetic

Current solutions to this question don't work...

I can't seem to get Symfony assetic to function. I have the following configured in my twig template

```
{% javascripts
    "/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"
    "/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"
    "/js/edged/jquery-ui.form.js"
    "/js/edged/jquery-ui.table.js"
    "/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"
    "/js/jquery.typewatch.js"

    output="/js/combined.js"
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

For same reason in development environment with use_controller = true I get the following error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_476d03f_0" as
>   such route does not exist.") in admin/view.html.twig at line 314.

When I set use_controller to false and do the whole assetic dump

```
app\console assetic:dump
```

The assets are not found, after digging around I noticed that the the _assetic route configurations have been removed from version 2.6 and 2.7, I think as of version 2.4 adding the configuration doesn't resolve any of the issues am facing.

Such a cool feature and I can;t get it working :(

Comment: If you are trying to load js file in web/js/...., you should remove the first slash in your asset files otherwise it will locate from the root directory

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however problem i doubt is caused by file path, if it was loading but I was not seen my files that would have been the case.

Answer (score 1):

Verify in your config.yml file under Assetic Configuration that you have the bundle registered.

`assetic:
     debug:  "%kernel.debug%"
     use_controller: false <-- this should be set to true in config_dev.yml
     bundles:
         - AppBundle <-- your bundle name`